# Where are my wireless error logs?

Tags: wireless, networking, ifconfig, logs

When I type `ifconfig` it shows:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:d5:3d:70:81:b3  
      inet addr:192.168.0.6  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e6d5:3dff:fe70:81b3/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:103728 errors:20 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:84061
      TX packets:79449 errors:46 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:127523350 (127.5 MB)  TX bytes:11102140 (11.1 MB)
      Interrupt:16
```

It shows errors 20, and errors 46 where can I find these errors?  I'm having trouble with my wireless and trying to debug.
Thanks!

Comment: Those "errors" are packet transmission errors for individual packet. They are not system errors which are logged anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

1. `iwconfig` gives more information about wifi networks than `ifconfig`
2. `sudo lshw -C network` will give you even more information
3. for logs, you could try looking in the `/var/log/dmesg` files, although that's a lot to wade through so you would want to check as soon as possible after you fail a connection.  I'm not sure there are dedicated interface logs - hopefully somebody else will have a better solution for you.

Comment: Is this still open or did you find a solution?