# Ubuntu 14.04 wifi not working Lenovo G560

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I have a Lenovo G560. Wifi will not connect. I've tried other threads but nothing works please help using Ubuntu 14.04. I will provide any output needed to help solve the problem.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0510]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:392e]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

**iwconfig**

```
eth0 no wireless extensions.

lo no wireless extensions.

wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:off/any
Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=27 dBm
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off Power Management:off
```

Comment: Is ubuntu detecting yuor wireless card ? **iwconfig** does list your card ?

Comment: eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off'

Comment: See if you can find wireless error logs in /var/log/dmesg , see this thread here :  http://askubuntu.com/questions/254804/where-are-my-wireless-error-logs

Comment: So i got it to work using some code from a thread but it drops out and reconnects every few minutes any thoughts on that

Comment: No can think much on that without more detail.. What was that other thread and code ? What was your resolution ?

Comment: Post the results from `rfkill list all`  please

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `linux-firmware-nonfree` via cable:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

and reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>